# Nuxt: SyntaxError Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When I was trying to open my Nuxt project in browser, I got the following error `SyntaxError Unexpected token {`. But I have found nothing wrong with the wrong information as shown in the following picture. Have anyone run into the same problem? Thanks a lot for your answers!
[image]

Comment: thats an syntax error.. I guess you have an `{` somewhere too much

Comment: @Ifaruki The error code in the `node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js`. It's a third party module which Nuxt depends on, not my own code.

Comment: Try reinstalling it, maybe the file got corrupted. But if this isn't your code, then your question is off-topic here. We're here to help you fix your code, not third party code.

Comment: can you please give us your page and its layout and also your `nuxt.config.js` code?

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmer mentioned， I have deleted the `node_modules` and rerun `npm install`, then it works well.